# Should I run 1/2" pex from a manifold to each fixture or 3/4"?

Tags: pex

Right now my setup is 3/4" cpvc pipe running from the water heater and then branching off into 1/2" cpvc pipe to each fixture. If I buy a manifold will there be a a pressure drop if I run 1/2" pex directly to each fixture?

Every manifold I've looked at has 1/2" outlets so not sure if that is a standard to use 1/2"  pipe to each fixture.

Answer (score 4):

The average fixture has no need for 3/4" inch, particularly with homerun piping from a manifold. 3/4" is really only needed for tub fillers with larger tubs, or showers with multiple shower heads.

Running 3/4" hot water lines to fixtures will significantly increase hot water wait times, and should be avoided when not necessary (and for lavatory sinks, I'd strongly recommend 3/8" hot water supply lines).

Comment: Any particular reason why I should use 3/8" for the bathroom sink and not other fixtures? If I was to use 3/8" for the sink, is there some kind of adapter to convert the manifold 1/2" outlet to 3/8"?

Comment: Bathroom sinks have the lowest flow rates, and the least need for flow, and people are more likely to want hot water quickly. You can use a reducing coupling to switch from 1/2" tubing to 3/8" tubing